# Auf den Sack gehen

Tags: etymology

Es gibt zwei Meinungen über die Redensart "jemandem auf den Sack gehen". Eine behauptet, es kommt aus dem Mittelalter, wo Säcke als Grenze gelegt wurden und bei Übertretung eine Schranke überschritten wurde. Die andere sagt aus, dass es eine sexuell konotierte Variation von "jemandem auf die Nerven gehen" ist, wobei man wahlweise anstatt von "Sack" auch "Eier" bzw. "Nüsse" o.ä. einsetzen kann.

Welches ist nun die richtige Herkunft?
Ist es unanständig, diese Redensart zu verwenden?

Comment: Zumindest assoziiere ich die Redewendung mit der zweiten Bedeutung. Ich empfinde sie nicht als unanständig im Sinne von Fäkalsprache, aber wenn eine Frau in meiner Gegenwart sagt, etwas ginge ihr auf den Sack, antworte ich gerne mal mit "anatomisch unmöglich". Falls die erste Variante der Herkunft zuträfe, würde ich tendenziell eher erwarten, dass es "über den Sack" hieße.

Comment: es gäbe sicher noch viele andere Beispiele von Redensarten, die eindeutig Doppeldeutig sind bzw. geworden sind, weil sie vielleicht ursprünglich gar nicht zweideutig gebraucht gedacht waren, aber von irgendeinem Schlaumeier als Freudscher Versprecher entlarvt wurden.

Comment: Nachdem in früheren Zeiten der _Sack_ auch synonym für den _Geldsack_ oder _Säckel_ verwendet wurde, könnte ich mir auch dies als Ursprung der Redensart vorstellen,

Comment: Ich habe auch immer gedacht, dass es ursprünglich darum geht, jemandem auf der Tasche zu liegen.

Comment: Wer behauptet denn, im Mittelalter seien Säcke als Grenze gelegt worden? Das klingt ziemlich aberwitzig. Klingt nach Stupededia.

Comment: @Volker Landgraf - Deshalb sagt frau ja auch: Du gehst mir auf die Eierstöcke, du Sackgesicht! Na ja, so oder so ähnlich. Gelegentlich. :-))

Comment: @multiplexetliber Habe ich zwar noch nie gehört, klingt aber durchaus logisch - muss ich mir merken :-)

Comment: Grimm hat *diese* Bedeutung von Sack noch nicht, wohl aber megaviele andere: https://woerterbuchnetz.de/?sigle=DWB#1.

Comment: Nicht jede Verwendung von "Sack" muss gleich eine sexuelle Konnotation haben. "Fauler Sack" und "alter Sack" haben das m.E. nicht - oder vermutet hier jemand ein pars pro toto? Man sollte jedenfalls nicht vorschnell andere Erklärungen ausschließen.

Comment: Eben, es gibt dutzende Möglichkeiten wie die Redensart zustande kommen könnte.

Comment: @KritikerderElche Nicht den "Fettsack" vergessen.

Answer (score 6):

Röhrich kennt die Redewendung nicht, wohl aber die mit *Nerven* und *Wecker*. Ob das daran liegt, dass es die mit *Sack* vor 1991 (Jahr der Erstausgabe) noch nicht gab oder ob die mit *Sack* aus welchem Grund auch immer nicht aufgenommen wurde, bleibt offen.

**Edit:**
Für den Fall, dass der Kommentar von Carsten S. vom 14.4.19 eines Tages verschwunden sein sollte: Er hat eine Belegstelle genannt, die Erstveröffentlichung eines Schauspiels in THEATER HEUTE (1986). Die Rw. mit *Sack* muss also bereits in der 1. Hälfte der 80er-Jahre existiert haben. Der Grund für die Nicht-Aufnahme bleibt weiterhin im Dunkeln.

---

Auf https://www.redensarten-index.de wird für die analoge Rw. mit *Keks* ergänzt: " Die Wendung gehört zu einer Reihe von jugendsprachlichen Abwehrfloskeln, in denen der Sprachwitz ganz beliebige Begriffe als Ersatz für das ältere "du gehst mir auf den Geist!" zur Verwendung anbietet (Senkel, Nüsse, Eier, Wecker, Zeiger u. a.)." Das klingt einigermaßen plausibel insofern, als es der Alltagserfahrung entspricht. Ob das allerdings ein "Indiz" im Geiselmann'schen Sinne ist?

Ob die Verwendung der Rw. "unanständig" ist, entscheidet vielleicht jede*r für sich. Sicher ist, dass die Rw. in einer Reihe von sozialen Kontexten unangemessen wäre. Harsch und derb ist sie auf jeden Fall.

Comment: Ich weiß nicht, wie reproduzierbar dieser Link ist, aber ich habe einen Beleg von 1986 oder früher gefunden: https://www.google.com/search?lr=lang_de&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1938%2Ccd_max%3A1995%2Clr%3Alang_1de&tbm=bks&ei=Uw2zXLnXK5H6wALJr4DwAw&q=%22mir+auf+den+sack%22&oq=%22mir+auf+den+sack%22&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.12...0.0.0.10664.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c..64.mobile-gws-serp..0.0.0....0.JEUdP8hNTi4 (Wahrscheinlich eine Übersetzung von [Glengarry Glen Ross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glengarry_Glen_Ross).)

Comment: Diese Redewendung gab es mit Sicherheit schon vor 1991. Vielleicht wurde sie bis dahin nicht irgendwo beschrieben, aber es gab sie.

Comment: Vielleicht nicht unanständig, aber Sprache die sich eines Geschlechsteils bedient wird normalerweise nicht in einer formellen Situation benutzt (mit Ausnahme von Fachsprache über Geschlechteilen, natürlich). Ich würde eine der Alternativen wählen, wobei ich Keks am "harmlosesten" finde.

Comment: Für vermeintliche Tabuworte historische Belege zu suchen ist ein relativ aussichtlosen Unterfangen, sollte man wissen.

Answer (score 4):

Ich würde auch auf die sexuelle Variante als Ursprung tippen. Vor allem weil es auch "So kleine Füße kann ich gar nicht haben" gibt.
Bekannt ist mir diese Spruch übrigens schon seit den 70-ern. Sowohl in der Schule kurz vorm Abi als auch bei der NVA, wo die Ausdrucksweise oft ordinär war, kam er vor.

Comment: multiplex et liber meint, dass die Redewendung erst seit den 1990-er oder evtl. 1980-er Jahren nachweisbar ist. Das könnte aber eine "westdeutsche" Perspektive sein, vielleicht ist der Ausdruck  in der DDR entstanden?

Comment: @multiplex et liber: Das mag sein, ich kann nur für mein Umfeld wo ich aufgewachsen bin berichten. Habe 1976 Abi gemacht und war danach bei der NVA.

Answer (score 3):

**[Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/auf_den_Sack_gehen) sagt:**

> **Herkunft:**
>   Sack wie Hodensack
>   Eine einzelne, alternative Erklärung ist: Nach einer Tradition, bei welcher kostbare Säcke zum Trocknen an der Grenze des Grundstücks ausgebreitet wurden. Trat jemand auf den Sack, überschritt er eine Grenze und ging wortwörtlich "auf den Sack".

Die als Alternative angebotene Erklärung erscheint mir nicht sehr plausibel. Säcke waren meiner Einschätzung nach zu keiner Zeit wertvoller als ihr Inhalt, und dass es üblich gewesen sein sollte, Säcke ausgerechnet an der Grundstückgrenze zu trocknen, erscheint mir unsinnig.

**[Wortbedeutung](https://www.wortbedeutung.info/auf_den_Sack_gehen/) sagt:**

> **Begriffsursprung:**
>   1) Sack wie Hodensack

Einen Punkt 2) gibt es nicht.

---

Auch ohne Recherche hätte ich sofort gesagt, dass sich diese Redewendung auf den Hodensack zurückgeht. Sie ist eine Abwandlung von

> auf die Nerven gehen

und verwandt mit

> auf den Geist gehen
>   auf den Keks gehen
>   auf den Wecker gehen
>   auf den Senkel gehen

und auch mit

> auf die Nüsse gehen

Bei letzterem sind keineswegs vegane Knabbereien gemeint, sondern die Hoden.

Comment: Tja... das ist nun viel Meinen und Glauben. Schön wäre es, wir hätten irgendwelche Indizien...

Comment: Ein Sack der in der Tür hängt dürfte dort viel besser trocknen, als wenn man ihn auf den Boden legt. Die Wiktionary-Quelle "wildbits" sieht auch mehr wie ein Klamaukblog aus - sie überhaupt zu erwähnen erinnert erheiternd an Alternativmedizin.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Wenn ein eindeutiger Wiktionary-Eintrag als Indiz gilt, kann ich den ja mal schnell umschreiben...

Comment: @sgf  Ich persönlich würde Sachen, die an Stellen publiziert sind, die mit "Wik" anfangen, nicht als Indiz nehmen. Außer als Indiz für sich selbst: "In Wik... stand am [Datum] folgendes dazu: ..." Das ist mir aber zu zirkulär.

Comment: @Christian: Wiktionary und Wikipedia sind natürlich nicht maßgebend, liegen aber doch sehr oft richtig und sind IMO sehr hilfreiche Quellen.

Comment: Vielleicht ist der Hodensack gemeint, vielleicht aber auch nicht. Deine Feststellung "Sie ist eine Abwandlung von *auf die Nerven gehen* und verwandt mit *auf den Geist / Keks / Wecker / Senkel gehen*" trifft zu, erklärt aber in keiner Weise, warum plötzlich der Hodensack ins Spiel kommen sollte.

Comment: Wie erklärst Du die Redewendung "[in den Sack hauen](https://www.synonyme.de/in-den-sack-hauen/)"? Wäre eine unangenehme Vorstellung, wenn hier auch der Hodensack gemeint wäre ...

Comment: @PaulFrost: Gar nicht. Ich kenne diese Redewendung nicht.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ist ja auch eine ganz andere Frage, insofern ist es nicht fair von mir, um eine Erklärung zu bitten. Es ging mir auch nur darum, ein weiteres Beispiel für die Verwendung von "Sack" zu geben, in dem es zwar Mutmaßungen über die Herkunft gibt, aber m.E. keine zwingenden Belege.

Answer (score -4):

Ich würde auf die sexuelle Bedeutung tippen, vielleicht nicht ursprünglich, jedoch für die längste Zeit.

Vorallem im Italienischen, ist das männliche Glied besonders häufig das Ziel von dysphemismen. Eine direkte Entsprechung für "auf den Sack gehen" habe ich auf die Schnelle nicht gefunden, das sollte aber noch nicht dagegen sprechen, denn ich bin weder des Italienischen mächtig, noch großartig an Beschimpfungen interessiert. Zu finden ist immerhin "coglione", pl. "coglioni" (Eier, Testikel) als übliche Profanität. So ist "auf die Eier gehen" eine übliche variante im Deutschen. Zudem überzeugt "porcocane" (Schweinehund), dass eine gewisse ähnlichkeit der Kraftsprache wohl kein Zufall sein kann.

Englisch kennt ebenso "get off my nuts". Ob dies nun auch davon kommt, dass Säcke voller Nüsse zum trocknen ausgelegt wurden und wie rohe Eier nicht zerlatscht werden dürften, sei dahingestellt.

Ich meine auch schon "jemandem auf den Schwanz treten" gehört zu haben, was wohl auf Tiere bezogen eine sehr sachliche Aussage ist und in Übertreibung auf das Menschliche Membrum übertragen werden kann. Das Wort [Penis](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/penis) bedeutet in Latein eben so viel (anhand anderer Indo-Europäischer Sprachen kann nur noch die Bedeutung *membrum* rekonstruiert werden, doch könnten andere Bedeutungen wegen Tabu verloren gegangen sein).

Comment: Das ist eine nette Hypothese, aber es fehlt jeglicher Beweis.

Comment: Lutsch mir nicht an die Titten, alter -- Das ist übrigens auch eine Ableitung von *jemandem nicht auf die zu trocknen an der Beleidigungsgrenze ausgelegten Tüten zu latsche*. Latsche er mir nich on die Tüten, alla. Was für Beweise, das erkläret sich dir nicht von selbst?

Comment: Habe zwar nicht gedwonvoted, aber Grimm hat dutzende Bedeutungen von 'Sack', und mir fallen für die Frage eine Menge ein die näherliegen als der Hodensack. Ich fabuliere mal der Blick ist hier getrübt durch freud'sche Fixierung auf ein Element aus vielen. Nicht alles dreht sich immer um Fortpflanzung ...