# X muss auf das Ganze gehen - what does this mean

Tags: preposition, accusative

The context concerns a certain component - for brevity let's call it X. Some believe this component is the name of a single part of a multi-part whole. Others believe it is the name of the multi-part whole itself. What does **"X muss auf das Ganze gehen"** mean? From the context I infer it means, effectively, **"X is the whole."** Am I correct? The word I care about most is this sentence is **aufgehen**. Dictionaries are not providing clear help. I see a common definition of aufgehen in dictionaries as **"rise up from."** That could possibly fit the context, but I suspect it is not correct. Despite the use of the accusative, which parallels my example, this idea does not seem to fit either: [Auf den Sack gehen](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/50658/auf-den-sack-gehen).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, your interpretation is wrong. The verb is not "aufgehen". One can tell this because the parts of a separable verb do not separate when it's in infinitive, so *aufgehen* is still *aufgehen* when combined with a modal verb like *müssen*.

*Auf etwas gehen* here means *to aim at something* or *to go for something*. So, the sentence literally means "X must go for the whole." A more idiomatic translation is probably "X has to go all in."

Comment: Fabulous, RHa! Thank you. In the back of my mind I wondered about aufgehen. I should have looked up gehen + auf. This now makes sense.